# How to set alarm clock when screen-time is active?

Tags: iphone, alarm, clock, screen-time

Often I don't go to bed until 'screen-time' is active.

I'd like to check/set my alarm, but screen-time doesn't let me use the alarm/clock app.  I couldn't find the "Clock" app in the "Always Allowed" configuration area of screen-time.

Can I set a wake-up alarm, without disabling screen-time every night?

Comment: Does Siri work while screen-time is active? In that case maybe she can help?